# Splittimg a string array

Tags: android, arrays, sorting

In my app I receive very long json with categories. Something like :

```
 final List<String> categories = Arrays.asList(new String[]{
                   "sport.summer.football"
                   "sport.summer.swimming"
                   "sport.winter.skijumping"
                   "movie.comedy"
                   "movie.horror"
                   "places.public.school"
                   "places.public.gym"
            });
```

I want to sort it to have list with categories(sport,movie,places and so on ...) , subcategories (horror,comedy,summer and so on ...) just to put it into the spinner.

I tried to split string into array :

```
for(String string : categories) {
                String[] parts = string.split("\\."); // escape .
                String mainCategory = parts[0];
                if(parts[0]!=null) {
                String subCategory = parts[1];
                String subSubCategory = parts[2];
            }
```

but it doesnt work. Any idea how to sort it, please ?

Comment: can you post your final list ? should look like ?

Comment: I think You should use a proper Json format for response . I this way this can be very  tricky.

Comment: It wasnt me who created that json :/  I need to deal with it